# "Virtual Device" for Microphone, Speakers, and Ringing

Tags: 14.04, sound, skype, microphone

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and and 4.3 Skype. I have a problem with sound. I have speakers connected and a microphone, but on top of that I have my USB headset plugged in. I can hear the sounds in youtube, I can hear music etc. but I cannot hear anything in skype. When I go to the options and try to change the microphone or speakers skype should use, I only get the option "Virtual Device". I've tried a lot of things I found on the web, but none of them seems to be working. I have tried typing "sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386" in the terminal, I have tried installing PulseAudio Volume Control, I tried reinstalling kernel, and I tried reinstalling the skype itself. I tried unlpugging speakers and my other mic, that didn't help either. I tried using skype with only my USB headset plugged in, and with only Speakers and Mic plugged in, didn't work either.. I don't know what to do, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Running pulseaudio on the command line gave me:

```
E: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Failed to open volume database '/home/niklaus/.pulse/63d4d5dc69352a2dc2c957aa513088e7-device-volumes': Keine Berechtigung
```

Called `rm -rf /home/niklaus/.pulse`. Then pulseaudio started without problem and Skype worked.